# Capturing events from slotted content in containing web component

Tags: javascript, web-component, dom-events, custom-element

I have a simple web component that contains a `<slot>`. It handles form data and inside I have UI elements that emit data change/selected events. I'm wondering how the web component can react on events emitted from slot content. Something along these lines:

```
<my-form-handler>
     <my-player-selector player-id="master"></my-player-selector>
     <my-player-selector player-id="challenger"></my-player-selector>
     <my-weapons-selector default="sword"></my-weapons-selector>
</my-form-handler>
```

I know I could write `<my-form-handler ondataSelected="someFunction">` presuming the selector elements emit `dataSelected` events. But that would require the code to live in the containing page instead of my-form-handler.

I'm not using any framework (Vue, Angular, React), just vanilla JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define in your custom element `<my-form-handler>` a handler in the `constructor()` or in the `connectedCallback()` method.

```
customElements.define( 'my-form-handler', class extends HTMLElement {
    conectedCallabck() {
        this.addEventListener( 'dataSelected', dsHandler )
   
        function dsHandler( ev ) {
             console.log( ev.type, ev.target.textContent )
        }
    }
} )
```

Of course you could use an arrow function if you want that `this` refers to the custom element object:

```
let dsHandler = ev => {
    console.log( ev.type, ev.target.textContent )
}
this.addEventListener( 'dataSelected', dsHandler )
```

You can also define the handler inline:

```
this.addEventListener( 'dataSelected', ev => 
    console.log( ev.type, ev.target.textContent )
)
```

NB: if you want the event handler to be a custom element method , you'll need to use `bind(this)` to be sure it can still access the custom element object.

```
customElements.define( 'my-form-handler', class extends HTMLElement {
    conectedCallabck() {
        this.addEventListener( 'dataSelected', this.dsHandler.bind( this ) )
    }
    dsHandler( ev ) {
        console.log( 'recever: %s / emitter: %', this.localName, ev.target.textContent )
    }
} )
```

Alternately, you can opt to a centralized solution with the help of the `handleEvent()` interface:

**1** Set the custom element itself as the listener:

`this.addEventListener( 'dataSelected', this )`

**2** Implement the `handleEvent()` method:

```
handleEvent( ev ) {
    switch( ev.type ) {
        case 'dataSelected':
            console.log( 'recever: %s / emitter: %', this.localName, ev.target.textContent )
            break
   }
}
```

Below a running snippet:

```js
customElements.define( 'my-form-handler', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.addEventListener( 'dataSelected', this )
    }
    handleEvent( ev ) {
        console.log( ev.type, ev.target.textContent )
    }
} )

customElements.define( 'my-player-selector', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()   
        this.addEventListener( 'click', () =>
          this.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( 'dataSelected', { bubbles: true } ) )
        )
    }    
} )
```

```html
<my-form-handler>
     <my-player-selector player-id="master">master</my-player-selector>
     <my-player-selector player-id="challenger">challenger</my-player-selector>
     <my-weapons-selector default="">sword</my-weapons-selector>
</my-form-handler>
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood question and answer. OP says SLOTs change, so doesn't that fire the standard ``slotchange`` event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/slotchange

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman the content of the <slot> is actually the Light DOM, and events emitted from it are not affected by the Shadow DOM. You could listen to slotchange but it is not necessary here (and nothing shows in the question that this content changed)